# I can't build recursive queries in MySQL 5+

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and have a few problems formulating a recursive query. This is my table:

```
> show columns from test;

+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| belong | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

> select * from test;

+----+--------+--------+
| id | name   | belong |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | value1 | 0      |
|  2 | value2 | 1      |
|  3 | value3 | 2      |
|  4 | value4 | 0      |
|  5 | value5 | 1,4    |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I would now like to select all records in whose belong field the ID 1 occurs and of course all records that are children of 1. In the example above, all records except the first.

As I have read, recursive queries are only possible from MySQL 8 onwards. So that's no use to me. However, I have also read that you can "simulate" recursion with subqueries and inline variables. But I have to admit that I can't do it and need a little help.

Comment: Your version does not support recursive **queries**. But you may use recursive stored procedures.

Comment: your first problem starts with comma seperated column data, that is not good see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad  next you can also check http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: record with id=4 belongs to `0`, why do you want to include that? (same question for record with id=5)

Comment: MySQL 5.x does not support recursive queries. You need to upgrade to MySQL 8.x to use recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

If record with id = 4, as in your example, has a `belong` of 0, then it should be all records except the first and the fourth.

I improved the design to reflect atomic values instead of a comma separated list of values.

So id 5 occurs once with a `belong` of 1, and once with a `belong` of 4. The database performance will thank you for that.

Had forgotten that MySQL in older versions does not even support the plain `WITH` clause. Then it gets slightly more complicated. And with many levels you had better write yourself a generator , in perl or python for example ...

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id, nm, belong) AS (
          SELECT 1 ,'value1', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 2 ,'value2', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3 ,'value3', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 4 ,'value4', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 5 ,'value5', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 5 ,'value5', 4
)
;
```

One way is to expand all CTE expressions wherever you'd otherwise use them:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    0 AS lvl
  , *
  FROM test
  WHERE belong=1
) AS lvl0
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    1 AS lvl
  , test.*
  FROM test
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      0 AS lvl
    , *
    FROM test
    WHERE belong=1
  ) AS lvl0 ON test.belong=lvl0.id
) AS lvl1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    2 AS lvl
  , test.*
  FROM test
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      1 AS lvl
    , test.*
    FROM test
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        0 AS lvl
      , *
      FROM test
      WHERE belong=1
    ) AS lvl0 ON test.belong=lvl0.id
  ) AS lvl1 ON test.belong=lvl1.id
) AS lvl2
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 28.938 ms. All rows formatted: 28.946 ms
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 27.098 ms. All rows formatted: 27.100 ms
-- out  lvl | id |   nm   | belong 
-- out -----+----+--------+--------
-- out    0 |  2 | value2 |      1
-- out    0 |  5 | value5 |      1
-- out    1 |  3 | value3 |      2
```

Another way is to UNION SELECT join-to-join-to-join , etc  several times..

```
SELECT
    0 AS lvl
  , *
  FROM test
  WHERE belong=1
UNION ALL SELECT
    1 AS lvl
  , lvl1.*
  FROM test AS lvl1 
  JOIN test AS lvl0 ON lvl1.belong=lvl0.id AND lvl0.belong=1
UNION ALL SELECT
    2 AS lvl
  , lvl2.*
  FROM test AS lvl2
  JOIN test AS lvl1 ON lvl2.belong=lvl1.id 
  JOIN test AS lvl0 ON lvl1.belong=lvl0.id AND lvl0.belong=1
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out  lvl | id |   nm   | belong 
-- out -----+----+--------+--------
-- out    0 |  2 | value2 |      1
-- out    0 |  5 | value5 |      1
-- out    1 |  3 | value3 |      2
```

Comment: http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/